# Simple exercises on frames

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$.
By repeating each element in $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ twice we obtain
$$
\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}=\left\{e_1, e_1, e_2, e_2, . .\right\},
$$
Prove that it is a tight frame with frame bound $A=2$. Moreover, if only $e_1$ is repeated we obtain
$$
\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}=\left\{e_1, e_1, e_2, e_3, . .\right\},
$$
which is a frame with bounds $A=1, B=2$. Prove it.

**My solution.**
A sequence $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of elements in $\mathcal{H}$ is a frame for $\mathcal{H}$ if there exist constants $A, B>0$ such that
$$
A\|f\|^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 \leq B\|f\|^2, \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{H} .
$$
Since $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$ we can write $f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i e_i$ where $c_i=\langle f, e_i\rangle$ and $\|f\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty |c_i|^2$.

Let $k=2j$. Then, for $j\in\mathbb N^+$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 = \left|\left\langle f, f_{2j-1}\right\rangle\right|^2+\left|\left\langle f, f_{2j}\right\rangle\right|^2=|c_{j}|^2+|c_{j}|^2$$
If we repeat this for each $j$ we have that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 =2 \sum_{j=1}^\infty |c_{j}|^2=2\|f\|^2$$
and then $A=2$.

For the second part of the exercise, we observe that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 =2|c_{1}|^2+\sum_{j=2}^\infty |c_{j}|^2\leq 2|c_{1}|^2+2\sum_{j=2}^\infty |c_{j}|^2=2 \|f\|^2$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 =2|c_{1}|^2+\sum_{j=2}^\infty |c_{j}|^2\geq |c_{1}|^2+\sum_{j=2}^\infty |c_{j}|^2=\|f\|^2$$
What do you think of my solution? Would anyone else have done differently?

Thank you!

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: You can mention that in the second case the bounded are optimal.

Comment: OK, thank you all!